# Getting user email from full name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, active-directory

I want to get email of users who are uploading documents in a library. You know there is a field called "Created By" which contain full name, so I want to read that name and then find that user's email.

Is there a way to do it without querying Active Directory?

There is another method (given below) but for it to work you need to know userid of user.

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
using (SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs["Website_Name"])
{
    SPUser oUser = oWebsite.AllUsers["User_Name"];

    oUser.Email = " E-mail_Address";

    oUser.Update();
}
```

What I have is full name only which is saved in "Created By" field of any library.

Comment: Do you want to read or update full name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code snippet

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;

SPDocumentLibrary oDocumentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)oWebsite.Lists["DocLib_Name"];

SPListItemCollection collListItems = oDocumentLibrary.Items;

foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
{
   var strAuthor = oListItem["Author"].ToString();
   var author = new SPFieldUserValue(web, strAuthor);
   SPUser user = author.User;
   var email = user.Email;
}
```

Comment: The code oListItem["Author"] as SPFieldUserValue is returning null even though if I see the value in Immediate Window then it displays users name. But when code is run the the variable "author" becomes null

Comment: Weird, it should work.. Can you try `(SPFieldUserValue)oListItem["Author"]` instead of `oListItem["Author"] as SPFieldUserValue` ?

Comment: Could it be because I am using this code in timer job?

Comment: When using second code you posted, getting error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue'."

Comment: @FrankMartin try the updated code in answer

Comment: Yes now your code works. And mine too which is given below. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by using the following code:

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection users = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, item["Author"].ToString());

    foreach (SPFieldUserValue userDetail in users)
    {
        SPUser user = userDetail.User;
        string email = userDetail.Email;
    }
```